# Removing items from boot menu / securely deleting free space

Tags: windows-7, boot

I just installed Windows 7 over win xp.  I deleted my windows.old folder and emptied it from the recycle bin but I still get older version of windows and a windows xp pro setup options in the boot menu.

I searched my computer using windows search for a boot.ini file but it did not find anything.

If I were to somehow securely delete my free space (some utility that wrote 0s) would that get rid of it.

Any advice?  Thank you.

Comment: The issue of Windows XP showing in your boot menu is not one of your computer still thinking the files are there - there is an entry in your BCD (Boot Configuration Data) store pointing towards the now-gone Windows XP install.

Comment: And I would edit my bcd through the command line since BCDEdit does not display this entry?  

I'll have to look into the command line config a bit more before I attempt anything because I am not completely competent with the CL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bcdedit from the command line as Administrator to modify boot options. Here is a list of the options:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28WS.10%29.aspx

You can also use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1).

Comment: I've used EasyBCD with much success before. Simple and easy to use.

Comment: Thank you.  Using BCD I was able to remove the earlier version of windows option.  Unfortunately Windows XP Pro Setup option still exists.  Any advice?

Comment: It does not list Windows XP Pro Setup anywhere in EasyBCD

Comment: If you type bcdedit from the command line, what does it display?

Comment: bcedit is not recongnized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file

Comment: Here is a tutorial:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2676-bcdedit-how-use.html

Did you run CMD as Administrator?